# Is it okay to make a plugin to the WordPress repo, but limit it's actions to maximum N events?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wordpress.org

Let's say you have a cleaner library. Is it okay to limit the free version that is hosted on the WordPress-repo to max clean 10.000 entries; after that you would have to pay for the pro version?

Comment: Questions about the plugin repository should be directed to them, as they are not questions about WordPress itself. You should review the plugin guidelines if you have any questions: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/, particularly #5.

Answer (score 0):

Trialware is not permitted (props @jacob):
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/#5-trialware-is-not-permitted

With the only exception being

> Attempting to upsell the user on ad-hoc products and features is acceptable, provided it falls within bounds of guideline 11 (hijacking the admin experience).

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/#11-plugins-should-not-hijack-the-admin-dashboard

Sounds like the feature must be in a separate plugin itself to be within the guidelines for submitting a plugin to WordPress.org

Just make sure you're not that guy that has a plugin that's super annoying trying to upsell :)

Comment: Wrong. https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/#5-trialware-is-not-permitted

Comment: I think I need to get more specific; say my plugin offers to find unused files. It can show you all of these files for free in the free version and you could manually delete them, but you can upgrade to PRO to delete all at once. It's an edge-case; but given that I provide some free functionality that is not limited, I guess that would still be within the bounds?

Comment: @JacobPeattie good point, seems there are still numerous plugins on WordPress.org that do it, including the freemius plugins which lock features behind the paywall.  I'll update the answer to reflect this, thanks for the clarification, that actually makes me happy that is the case :)